# Shell : How to deal with filenames that contain `\n` or ` ` in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "Use: "$0" <file_name>"
  echo "Convert files from GBK to UTF8"
  exit
fi

for i in $*

  # Generate temp file to avoid Bus error
  iconv -f GBK -t utf-8 "$i" -o "$i.tmp"
  mv "$i.tmp" "$i"
done
```

The problem is `$i` may contains `\n`,  or other wired chars, that makes the script fails to execute(even I've already wrapped it with ""). Is there any way to ignore those characters ?

Answer (score 5):

When looping over all the input arguments in a shell script, you should always use `"$@"`.  Not `$*`, not `$@`, and not `"$*"`.  Only with `"$@"` do you get full proper handling of all input strings.

P.S.: Always start your scripts with `set -e` and probably `set -o pipefail`.  Then your script will stop on the first error, rather than running wild with untested behaviors.

Comment: Thanks ! but is there anyway to deal with filenames that contain `\n` or other wired chars ?

Comment: Yes, iterating over "$@" handles all names correctly.

Comment: In my case, I find `$@` split some of my filenames into several lines!

Comment: `"$@"` not `$@`

Comment: It's probably better to do your own error handling than to rely on `set -e`. See [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @chepner: Almost nobody really does their own error handling.  I've been writing Bash scripts for production for many years using `set -e`.  I haven't encountered any serious problem with it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck There's a big difference between "people who have been writing production Bash scripts for years" and "people who still need to ask why `$*` isn't doing what they want." Save `set -e` for when you understand when it might fail, and focus on recognizing which failed commands are critical.